# A question about the zeros of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

In the book "theory of functions of a complex variable" by  A.I. Markushevich (p374-375, volume 1), the setting of $ f_n(z) $ is given in the following lemma and therom 17.4

[image]
[image]

[image]

From the lemma, the author suggests a easy way to find out all the zeros of $ f(z)$ in the Remark 2. Here, I think the first formula in Remark 2 is wrong and the right factorization should be 
$$ f_n(z) = (z-z_0)^{k0}(z-z_1)^{k1}...(z-z_m)^{km}g_n(z) .$$

Comment: It's impossible to explain this unless you tell us what $f_n$ is.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich, my friend , the background information has been added, I hope I can still get your help.

Comment: Hmm, I think you are right.  Does it change anything?

Comment: I've had students get things completely wrong because they thought "e.g." meant the same thing as "i.e.". In fact "e.g." means "for example". So in Remark 2 he's not talking about the general case, he's restricting attention to the case where each $f_n$ has only one zero.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich  Thank you, sir. I really need to be careful in reading the book.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you want only one $z_n$ for each individual zero you will need to have an exponent too. But in the text it says "number of times the linear factor appears" so I suppose they allow $z_n = z_m$ for $n\neq m$. I agree your approach would be more convenient if the function had zeros of higher order than one.

Comment: My friend, some background information has been added, please help me again, Thanks.